# How can I collapse similar overloaded functions into one function C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have the following two identical functions but with different arguments and I want to collapse them into one function. How can I do that?

```
template <typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const set<T>& v) {
    os << "{";
    char comma[3] = {'\0', ' ', '\0'};
    for (const auto& e : v) {
        os << comma << e;
        comma[0] = ',';
    }
    return os << "}";
}

template <typename F, typename S>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const map<F, S>& v) {
    os << "{";
    char comma[3] = {'\0', ' ', '\0'};
    for (const auto& e : v) {
        os << comma << e;
        comma[0] = ',';
    }
    return os << "}";
}
```

This is assuming that the operator <<(ostream& os, const pair< K, V > p) is already defined so the map cout << e should work properly.

I want something similar to the following pseudo-code:

```
template <typename F, typename S, typename X=set or map>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const X<F, S>& v) {
    os << "{";
    char comma[3] = {'\0', ' ', '\0'};
    for (const auto& e : v) {
        os << comma << e;
        comma[0] = ',';
    }
    return os << "}";
}

cout << aMap << aSet; // should work!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use templates.  Pull the common code into a separate function.

```
template <typename T>
ostream& WriteRange(ostream& os, const T& v) {
    os << "{";
    char comma[3] = {'\0', ' ', '\0'};
    for (const auto& e : v) {
        os << comma << e;
        comma[0] = ',';
    }
    return os << "}";
}

template <typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const set<T>& v) {
    return WriteRange(os, v);
}

template <typename F, typename S>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const map<F, S>& v) {
    return WriteRange(os, v);
}
```

Comment: Oh. That's simple I didn't think of it!

Comment: If I also want to use it for vector as well, but I want to use "[" instead of "{", can I check whether v is of type vector?
Something like if (v instanceof vector) os << "[" else os << "{"

Comment: @off99555, just pass the bracket characters as arguments (with defaults).

Answer (score 0):

You can add this type trait ,which within my research, i havn't found in the stl.

```cpp
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_T_iterable : std::false_type {};

// this gets used only when we can call std::begin() and std::end() on that type
template <typename T>
struct is_T_iterable<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::begin(std::declval<T>())),
                                    decltype(std::end(std::declval<T>()))>> :
       std::true_type {};
```

and you can use this in two ways

C++11 and above:

```cpp
template<class T>
constexpr is_iterable = is_T_iterable<T>::value;

template <class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const T& v) {
    static_assert(is_iterable<T>,
                  "T is not an iterable class");
    os << "{";
    char comma[3] = {'\0', ' ', '\0'};
    for (const auto& e : v) {
        os << comma << e;
        comma[0] = ',';
    }
    return os << "}";
}
```

or in C++20 and above you can use concepts:

```cpp
template<class T>
concept iterable = is_T_iterable<T>::value;

template <iterable T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const T& v) {
    os << "{";
    char comma[3] = {'\0', ' ', '\0'};
    for (const auto& e : v) {
        os << comma << e;
        comma[0] = ',';
    }
    return os << "}";
}
```

both these methods are compile time so it will add no overhead. depends on what you find most readable to you.